# Can't work out what is missing from my R function code - stopping it from running well

Tags: r, function, bayesian

I'm trying to do Bayesian Occupancy Analysis with site covariates. My first step is making a function. I keep on getting the + in my R console indicating it thinks my code is incomplete. Having ran lines individually I am pretty certain the issue lies in the first line of code. However, I can't work out where exactly I've missed something out and hence where the problem originally lies.

```
data.fn <- function(R = 39, T = 14, xmin= 0, xmax= 1, alpha.psi = 0.4567,
                beta.psi = 0.0338, alpha.p = 0.4, beta.p = 0.4) {
y <- array(dim = c(R,T)) #This creates an array for counts
  #Ecological Process
  #Covariate values
X <- sort(runif(n=R, min = xmin, max = xmax))
#Expected occurence-covariate relationship
 psi <- plogis(alpha.psi + beta.psi *X) #this applies the inverse logit

 #Add Bernoulli Noise - drawing indicator of occurence (z) from bernoulli psi 
 z<- rbinom(n = R, size = 1, prob = psi)
 occ.fs <- sum(z) #"Finite Sample Occupancy"
 "Make a census"
  p.eff <- z*p
  for (i in 1:T) {
    y[,i] <- rbinom(n=R, size = 1, prob = p.eff)
  }
}
```

There's more code - i.e. the {} function is complete but the issue started before that was ran and I keep having issues uploading the code into Stack.
The error message is simply + all down the left hand side of the R console

EDIT

Could there be something wrong with how R is sensing stuff? For instance with the following code

```
naive.pred <- plogis(predict(glm(apply(y, 1, max) ~ X + I (X^2),
                             family = binomial)))
```

I got the error message - unexpected symbol (the bracket) in the family = binomial yet each bracket is paired correctly- there's no extra unnecessary brackets?

Comment: The `+` as a prompt means: R attends further input to end a structure. It can be a missing `}` for a block or a missing `)` or a missing `"` ... In your question there is no `}` for the code block of your function.

Comment: Now that you've updated the example so the `{` is closed, what happens when you start a fresh R session and run the example code? (For me it works as expected, no errors and the function is added to the global environment)

Comment: It still doesn't work for me? I still get the exact same error message with a fresh R session - I still get the + message but when I run individual bits of code seperately it has stopped giving me the + message

Comment: For `naive.pred` are you looking for estimated occupancy at all `R` sites or the regression coefficents? On top of this, the `naive.pred` code functions just fine assuming that you have `X` and `y` in your global environment.

Comment: Tbh my first aim is getting the code to work and then I'll refine these other more precise features. The code doesn't seem to work on my R studio at all but appears to work on all those commenting etc. Why could this be?

Comment: If you run the code block [here](https://rdrr.io/snippets/) there is no error and the function is assigned properly. Are you sure you are *only* running the first code block in the question after starting a new R session (and not after running other code)? If so, the only other possibility I see is that you've put some incomplete code in your .Rprofile

Answer (score 0):

While I did not see a `+` issue when I looked over your code, you are not simulating the observed data correctly and there was a `p` object inside your function that did not have an argument passed to it. You did create a logit linear predictor for `psi` using `alpha.psi` and `beta.psi`, however you are lacking a logit linear predictor for the probability of detecting a species given that they are there using `alpha.p` and `beta.p`. Assuming that the covariate `X` is used for both the latent occupancy state and the observation model the code should become.

```
data.fn <- function(R = 39, T = 14, xmin= 0, xmax= 1, alpha.psi = 0.4567,
                                        beta.psi = 0.0338, alpha.p = 0.4, beta.p = 0.4) {
    y <- array(dim = c(R,T)) #This creates an array for counts
    #Ecological Process
    #Covariate values
    X <- sort(runif(n=R, min = xmin, max = xmax))
    #Expected occurence-covariate relationship
    psi <- plogis(alpha.psi + beta.psi *X) #this applies the inverse logit

    #Add Bernoulli Noise - drawing indicator of occurence (z) from bernoulli psi 
    z<- rbinom(n = R, size = 1, prob = psi)
    occ.fs <- sum(z) #"Finite Sample Occupancy"
    # Linear predictor for detection,
    #  assuming the same covariate is used for detection
    p.eff <- plogis(alpha.p + beta.p * X)
    for (i in 1:T) {
        y[,i] <- rbinom(n=R, size = 1, prob = p.eff * z)
    }
    return(list(y = y, z = z, X = X, occ.fs = occ.fs))
}
```

This code assumes that you are passing logit scale parameters to the data, so if you are trying to simulate data such that `X` has a very marginal and positive influence on occupancy then you are off to the races, so to speak. If you are looking for a more pronounced effect, than you should increase the effect size.  Finally, 39 site is very few for an occupancy analysis given that binary deteciton / non-detection data is quite information poor. Don't be surprised if you posterior estimates you get from analyzing the dataset do not actually return the parameters used to simulate the data.